# Google custom Icon not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to load a custom icon for Google Maps API v3. The code I have is as follows:

```
 $(function(){

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.2542586, -83.8873974),
      zoom: 10
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


   $('.valley').on('click', function(){

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.000, -83.0073974);
      var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 14,
       center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      var iconMarker = 'pin2.jpg'
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatlng,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
       icon: iconMarker,
       map: map,
       title:"Hello"
      });
  });

});
```

The following script is in the 'application.html.erb' file (i've taken out my apikey)
  `<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=false"></script>`

Pretty straight forward and the actual map loads, but for some reason the rails app is not finding the `.jpg`for the icon. I've placed it in various locations, currently it is in the root folder. For some reason it is trying to load the file as a `text/html` file instead of an image. I replaced the image with another image that is loading properly on the web page, and I still get a 404 with the browser trying to load it as an `text/html`
[image: loading as a text/html]

Here is the error in the console
[image: 404 error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
var iconMarker = '/assets/pin2.jpg';
```